# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {} failed

Tags: c#, com, interop

I'm getting this error when running a C# Windows Forms application:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {} failed 
due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception 
from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

This is appearing in the IDE on 32-bit Windows XP. The COM component in question is a 3rd party dll which is definitely registered ok on the machine in question. My project is targetting x86 ok. I only seem to get the error when instantiating a particular class of the component, other classes that I use are working fine.

I've tried with the component just added directly as a reference and have also created an interop assembly and referenced that but get the same result. Have unregistered and reregistered the component using regsvr32 to no avail.

If I reference the same component in a VB6 application and instantiate the same class it works fine! I am thoroughly confused, can anyone offer any suggestions which might help me out?!

Thank you.

Comment: Well, you eliminated the obvious reasons.  What's left is DLL Hell, the type library you used might not match the actual installed component.  You can get more insight by running SysInternals' ProcMon utility.  You'll see your program searching the registry for the CLSID key.  You can look at the type library directly with the OleView.exe program.  File + View Typelib.  You'd typically need help from the component vendor to sort this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by changing the instantiating line from:

```
Component.MyObject test = new Component.MyObject();
```

to

```
Component.MyObject test;
```

Not sure at this stage why that should work but it does so I can carry on! I'm still instantiating the other classes used with the new keyword.